# Solve the inequality $-1<\frac{x}{\log(x-1)(x-1)}<1$

Tags: inequality

> Can you help me solve the inequality:
>
> $$-1<\dfrac{x}{\log(x-1)(x-1)}<1$$

I try:

$-1<\dfrac{x}{\log(x-1)(x-1)}$

$=\dfrac{-\log(x-1)(x-1)}{x}<0$

$=0<\log(x-1)$

$= \log(x-1)>0$

$= x-1>10^0$

$= x>2$

In the second inequation I'm having more problems

Comment: $\log(x-1)$ will be positive if $x>2$ and negative if $1<x<2$ so for the other half of the inequality you will have to consider those two cases.

Comment: You have to make sure that you don't multiply an inequality be a negative number without reversing it. For $x>0$ i Found the solution set to be $(0,a)$ where a is the unique positive number with $e^{a} =(a-1)^{2}$. You can a picture of the exponential function and the parabola $y=(x-1)^{2}$ to see when $e^{x} > (x-1)^{2}$.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This inequality cannot be solved algebraically. It can be solved approximately using a [graphing utility](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

The function $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\log\left((x-1)^2\right)}$ has a vertical asymptote at $x=2$ and has removeable discontinuities at $x=0$ and $x=1$ since $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(10)$ and $\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=0$.

Although one may analyze the inequality further, ultimately one must resort to using non-elementary methods or graphing to find the solution.

The approximate solution of the inequality is $(0.251,1)\cup(1,1.24)$.

Here is a wide view and a detailed view of the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\log\left((x-1)^2\right)}$ together with the graphs of $y=1$ and $y=-1$ with the intersection points indicated by their coordinates.

[image: Wide view of functions]

[image: Narrow view of functions]

Comment: Is there any proof of why it isn't solvable algebraically?

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_  The numbers $0.251$ and $1.24$ are approximate solutions to the transcendental equation $10^x(x-1)^2-1=0$.

Comment: I am wondering why we can't solve the equation algebraically? Is there any proof? And what do you mean for 'non-elementary methods'? @John

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ The only tag given is "inequality" and from the erroneous approach taken by OP I assumed a knowledge of pre-calculus alone. The roots can be found to any degree of accuracy using Newton's Method, but that requires knowledge of differentiation.